# Adding conditions to excel export worksheets loop

Tags: excel, vba

Currently learning VBA in bits and pieces.

Confused on where to insert a condition in the following piece to check each worksheet respectively on cell address E8 for example for ANY entry other than “”.

```
Sub SaveWorkshetAsPDF()
Dim ws As Worksheet
timestamp = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy ")
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Select
ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & timestamp & ws.Name & ".pdf"
Next ws
End Sub
```

Any assistance would be amazing.

Want it to stop exporting if a value is present in a specified cell.

Comment: `If Len(ws.Range("E8").Value) = 0 Then` maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should get you what you need. I included some comments that might help out a little and give you a method to have a condition to check.

A couple notes to improve:

- Always good to define variable such as `timestamp`.
- No need to actively select the sheet, you can get the file's workbook path using the `parent` property.
- For items that are hard-coded, I'm a fan of putting the values at the top of the macro as `constants`. It makes changing things easier.

Hope this helps.

```
Sub SaveWorkshetAsPDF()
    Const theValueToStop As String = "Stop" 'or whatever, if it's a number change to Long
    Const theAdddress As String = "E8" 'makes it easier to find and change if needed.

    Dim ws As Worksheet, timestamp As String

    timestamp = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy ")

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        'no neeed to select use parent property for address.
        'ws.Select
        
        If ws.Range(theAdddress).Value <> theValueToStop Then
           ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
           ws.Parent.Path & "\" & timestamp & ws.Name & ".pdf"
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that PGSystem tester. In addition to immediately working I actually understand what went wrong now!